# VBA CopyFromRecordset giving extremely slow performance

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to execute a SQL query through VBA and then paste the results into a table in an excel file.  I noticed when doing this that the vast majority of the time is being spent pasting the records, and I cannot figure out why.  My code is as below

```
Option Explicit

Sub SQLTest()
    
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Connection variables
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cnnstr As String
    
    'Input variables
    Dim sql As String
    Dim tablename As String
    Dim tablelocation As String
    
    'timer for profiling
    Dim dTime1, dTime2 As Double
    dTime1 = Timer
    
    'Read in the query and the output parameters
    sql = Worksheets("Queries").Range("A2").Value
    tablelocation = Worksheets("Queries").Range("B2").Value
    tablename = Worksheets("Queries").Range("C2").Value
             
    'Open Connection and execute query
    cnnstr = "driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};system=SYSTEM;translate=1;Prompt=Complete;User ID=ID;Password=PASSWORD;QueryTimeout=0"
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    cnn.Open (cnnstr)
    rst.Open sql, cnn
  
    'Paste profiling
    dTime2 = Timer
    
    'Paste Query results into table
    Worksheets(tablelocation).ListObjects(tablename).Range(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rst
    
    'Output run time
    MsgBox ("Total Time : " & Timer - dTime1 & " Paste Time : " & Timer - dTime2)

End Sub
```

When I run this I get the total run time is 93.656 seconds with the CopyFromRecordset line accounting for 92.003 seconds.  I have run this a few times and these numbers seem consistent.  Is there any way to reduce the amount of time it takes to paste this data?

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? Consider switching off things like screenupdating. Finally, as adding to ListObject, I find it faster to add rows outside of a table range then extend the table range, removing any blank rows, rather than trying to add into existing table range direct (for large row counts).

Comment: There are only around 300 rows.  Screenupdating is set to false, and when i get rid of the table and just set the output to A1 on the output sheet i still get similar results

Comment: Once the recordset is open, how long does it take to complete a call like `rs.MoveLast` ?  Is it possible it's taking a long time to fetch the rest of the records?

Comment: rs.MoveLast only takes about a second to run, while the pasting is still taking a minute and a half

Comment: You should Show your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question while struggling with legacy code which had `CopyFromRecordSet`. In my experience, it is horribly slow for anything more than a trivial number of lines.

Try extracting the Recordset information into 2D Variant Array and set the Value property of the respective Excel Range. Chunk your data if you think memory is going to be a constraint. The solution is involved. You'll need to do the bounds checks and also transpose the data before setting the Value property. I implemented the code below:

```
Sub CopyFromRecordset(rngStart As Range, rstData As Variant)
    Dim buffer As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    If InStr(TypeName(rstData), "RecordSet") > 0 Then
        rstData.MoveLast
        rstData.MoveFirst
        ' Pull data into a "buffer"
        buffer = rstData.GetRows(rstData.RecordCount)
        ' Need to transpose data before pasting
        ReDim buffer2(UBound(buffer, 2), UBound(buffer, 1)) As Variant
        For i = 0 To UBound(buffer, 1)
            For j = 0 To UBound(buffer, 2)
                buffer2(j, i) = buffer(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
        ' Paste the values from buffer into range
        rngStart.Application.Range(rngStart, rngStart.Offset(UBound(buffer2, 1), UBound(buffer2, 2))).Value = buffer2
    Else
        Debug.Print ("Expected RecordSet, found " & TypeName(rstData))
    End If
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
CopyFromRecordSet Worksheets(tablelocation).ListObjects(tablename).Range(2, 1), rst
```